# How does std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() work

Tags: c++, numeric-limits

I recently learnt [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71903912/18839862):

> The correct way to get the largest possible value of a numeric type on your system is to use std::numeric_limits. In particular, we can use `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` etc.

When reading the documentation of [std::numeric_limits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), I found that `std::numeric_limits` is a class template. My question is: How does `std::numeric_limits` find the type-/system-dependent largest/smallest value? I mean, how is that class template implemented?

In certain cases, I have seen that cppreference has a section labeled "Possible implementation" but, in the case of `std::numeric_limits` there is no such section.

I know that it will vary across platforms, but I just want to see one possible case to get an idea of how it is working and if is there a way to find the maximum/minimum value for a given type/system manually.

Comment: It's a template, you have the source for it, open up the header. https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/limits.html is an example.

Comment: It's the maximum value for the implementation of C++ you're coding in. So, the way it knows what the maximum value is is... The compiler implementers are the same people setting both values. It's not like there's some value belonging to the OS or underlying hardware that the language is querying.

Comment: You might be curious to know that you can simply look in your compiler's header files for `std::numeric_limits` and see absolutely everything about it, and how it works. Hint: the maximum value of an unsigned integer type T is `static_cast<T>(~0)`, for example. However most implementations simply use explicit specializations.

Comment: @NathanPierson Ok, so compiler implementers hard code these values?

Comment: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/limits#L1060

Comment: @康桓瑋 So, they're using `__INT_MAX__` at many places where does that come from? And they're also using `_GLIBCXX_USE_CONSTEXPR` when writing for example `static _GLIBCXX_USE_CONSTEXPR bool is_specialized = true;`. What does `_GLIBCXX_USE_CONSTEXPR` mean. Is it a macro. I know that we can write: `static bool is_specialized = true;` but what does `static _GLIBCXX_USE_CONSTEXPR bool is_specialized = true;` mean.

Comment: Constants like `__INT_MAX__` are built-in symbols that are defined by the compiler itself. Symbols like `_GLIBCXX_USE_CONSTEXPR` are defined by the C++ library, based on different symbols that are defined by the compiler. For gcc, https://gcc.gnu.org/ contains a complete documentation for the compiler and its built-in symbols.

Comment: `std::numeric_limits` was specifically introduced that no manual detection was needed. More compatible and less error-prone and no autoconf needed to find things out (https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Generic-Compiler-Characteristics.html#Generic-Compiler-Characteristics)

Answer (score 0):

> How does `std::numeric_limits` find the type-/system-dependent largest/smallest value? I mean, how is that class template implemented?

Nothing is "found". `std::numeric_limits` is simply instantiated differently for different types. Have a look at [its instantiation for `int`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/limits#L1058), within [the GNU implementation of the C++ standard library](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3).

The instantiation values are such that, on the target platform, they are valid.